# sieve mail regular expression not working

Tags: regex, sieve-language

I'm using [smartsieve](http://smartsieve.sourceforge.net/) web gui to manage my sieve filters.
I have a problem with regular expression match.

I'm sending myself a test email with subject in format: testXX (where X is a number between 0 and 9).

When I define a filter:
If message 'Subject:' matches regular expression [0-9]+
generated rule is:

```
elsif allof (header :regex "subject" "[0-9]+") {
    fileinto "INBOX/Tests";
}
```

message is processed correctly

but any time when I add any text to regular expression... matching fails
If message 'Subject:' matches regular expression test[0-9]+
generated rule is:

```
elsif allof (header :regex "subject" "test[0-9]+") {
    fileinto "INBOX/Tests";
}
```

When I tested my code using [online tool](https://www.fastmail.fm/docs/sieve/sievetest.php) to test sieve scripts everything worked fine, even with more complicated expression. I do need more complicated expression, but i stripped it, because I need to find where the problem is.

Comment: its more complicated problem, I somehow solved this little issue, but more problems ahead - sieve and filtering of utf-8 encoded messages...

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If mails that "testXX" and "XX" mail should moved "INBOX/Test", you may do this.

For example:

```
elsif allof (header :regex "subject" "(test)?\d+") 
{
  fileinto "INBOX/Tests";
}
```

For an example refer to [this](http://regexr.com?38dcd).